# connecting pc and ethernet device through lan

Tags: java

I know that socket programming should be used to connect between the computer and ethernet device which are connected through.I am making ethernet device as the server and computer and the client. when i try to run the client and connect i am getting connection refused error.how to overcome this.

```
my ethernet device IP address- 192.168.1.3
port number is- 3000.

my pc ip address - 192.168.1.22
```

when i try doing the same thing using two ps's it is working fine but not with one pc and other ethernet device.

code for this would be helpful.
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running windows?  If so, start by disabling the firewall to see if that is the problem, i.e. test and re-instate the firewall.

Comment: firewall is disabled, i am running windows

Comment: can anyone help me with this issue

Comment: Maybe look at something like WinPCap, to see what is actually happing on the network layer.

Comment: I have an app similar which i require ,that desktop app is working fine but my app is not working i have used the similar code in my app

Comment: every time when i am getting an error in this line.

Comment: Socket s=new Socket("192.168.1.3",3000);

Comment: I am getting IOException in the above line. how to resolve this